# How to access the "change the size of all items" in the Display in Control Panel after changing it to 500%

Tags: windows-8.1, control-panel

By mistake, the option on "custom sizing options" was set at 500% in the section "change the size of all items".
The result is all elements on the screen are huge, and whereas I am able to reach the display section and through tab I am able to navigate some options on the left panel, I am unable to reach the change the size of all items section.

I have tried several things to revert it to 100%, but all have failed so far:

Restart on safe mode. Displaying it on a different monitor and proyector using both hdmi and vga. Uninstalling the graphics driver didnt help. Using the "zoom" only has option to zoom in. Changing the screen orientation to vertical in hopes of accessing more options allowed me to see the left panel but not more. Using ctrl + mouse doesnt change the size inside the Display section. The computer doesnt have a restoration point to go back to, and I cant uninstall the applications because it isnt my laptop.

I have been searching for the correct command to execute but the closest I have found is "Display Properties control desk.cpl" and it is not the command I need. By the way, the  computer is a lenovo using windows 8.1 in spanish. I have tried in other computers, for example a dell in windows 8 and the percetage is limited to 200%, so I cant test it correctly.

If somebody has a solution or any suggestion please share.
English is not my mother language so please excuse the grammar and misspelings.